# Usuário do SOpt entra "na faixa" na maior conferência de experts Microsoft

Tags: debate, comunidade

## MVPConf 2019

Não posso relevar detalhes ainda, mas será um evento épico! Não é marketagem, se tudo der certo verão algo inovador. Aguardem!

---

## Obrigado pela presença

O evento foi um sucesso, chegamos até bater records :)

Fiquei feliz pela minha palestra ter sido muito elogiada, mas não tão feliz por ter ficado muita gente pra fora dela. Vocês tem um pouco de responsabilidade de eu estar lá palestrando. Vou postar mais sobre o que rolou nas minhas redes sociais.

Quem não foi perdeu algo muito legal pra conhecimento e networking. Não vejo a hora de participar de mais um.

## Ingressos esgotados

Adoraria fazer isto pra todo mundo, mas só dá para fazer para um usuário. Mas posso fazer para mais usuários com 50% de desconto.

Conhecem o [MVP National Conference](https://mvpconf.com.br/)?

Talvez não, é o primeiro ano que os MVPs da Microsoft se reúnem em um evento para retribuir para a comunidade oferece conteúdo de qualidade. Ocorrerá dias 06 e 07 de abril na [UNIP Tatuapé em São Paulo](https://www.google.com/maps/place/UNIP+Tatuap%C3%A9/@-23.52824,-46.565133,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x92fde7c6c7b0739a!8m2!3d-23.5282398!4d-46.5651333?hl=pt-BR).

[image: MVPConf]

Para quem não conhece o programa de MVP, ele é uma premiação que a Microsoft oferece para profissionais que contribuem com conteúdo de qualidade para a comunidade gerando impacto positivo da evolução e desenvolvimento de outros profissionais. [Vá lá conhecer](https://mvp.microsoft.com/pt-br/). Fala comigo se você acha que deveria ser MVP também.

[Fui nomeado ano passado](https://mvp.microsoft.com/pt-br/PublicProfile/5002397) graças ao SOpt. E agora queria retribuir para vocês.

Para ganhar o *voucher* você precisa ser um usuário que está contribuindo no site. Todo mundo tem chance de ganhar se é um profissional engajado. Não importa quem, mesmo que você não goste de mim pode ganhar, sem discriminação.

Se sobrar alguns posso até distribuir *vouchers* para quem não contribui mas demonstra estar querendo evoluir de forma efetiva.

Por favor para não tumultuar aqui, prefira entrar em contato comigo no privado em alguma rede social. Tenho várias no [meu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero?tab=profile), adiciona lá, mesmo que não queira o *voucher*.

Fale porque merece. Alguns nem precisa isto porque o merecimento é óbvio.

Só peça o *voucher* se vai usar. Se for de 100% de desconto exijo que a pessoa vá no evento. Se for 50% tem que usar o *voucher*, e acho que deveria ir de qualquer jeito.

100% das vendas dos ingressos será revertido para entidades filantrópicas. Se deseja contribuir mesmo sem ir para o evento:

APAE - Associação de Pais e Amigos dos Excepcionais

```
CAIXA ECONÔMICA FEDERAL
AG: 0504
CC: 01823-0
CNPJ: 89.078.059/0001-06
```

Lar da Criança Ninho de Paz

```
ITAU UNIBANCO AS
Agência: 467
CC: 611109
CNPJ 53.372.454/0001-50
```

Outra forma de contribuir é não usar *voucher* e pagar os 100%.

Estarei palestrando lá e gostaria de conhecer vocês.

Eu pago a passagem pra você vir. Ah não, 1o. de abril já passou :P Então não posso pagar :(

Se você nunca foi a uma conferência, deve ir. Além de todo o conteúdo fará *networking*, terá uma experiência diferente e isto agregará na sua vida profissional, e até pessoal. Não perca!

Dúvidas?

Comment: Não entendi uma coisa: você vai sortear os vouchers, é isso?

Comment: @bfavaretto não, vou escolher de acordo com merecimento e necessidade. Na verdade o critério principal é a pessoa querer ir mesmo.

Comment: Quantos vouchers você tem para distribuir?

Comment: @VictorStafusa não sei ao certo, mas os de 50% acho que consigo mais se precisar. De 100% posso dispor de 1, mas também pode ver o que dá pra fazer dependendo do que esteja pensando.

Comment: Sabe dizer se as palestras do evento foram ou serão disponibilizadas em vídeo?

Comment: @bfavaretto As Keynotes foram gravadas. As palestras serão gravadas no estilo UFC Live da Globo :) Mas até onde eu sei só serão disponibilizadas para quem se inscreveu. Vou gravar a minha semana que vem. Estou sendo convidado para outros eventos.