# Qual a política para divulgação de eventos/cursos no Meta?

Tags: debate

Me chamou bastante atenção [esta postagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6940/usu%C3%A1rio-do-sopt-entra-na-faixa-na-maior-confer%C3%AAncia-de-experts-microsoft?cb=1) que divulga um evento da Microsoft aqui no Meta.

Minha impressão era de que a comunidade não encarava com bons olhos esse tipo de divulgação por aqui... Fazendo uma busca rápida só encontrei divulgação de mais um [evento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6216/devday-2017-belo-horizonte), fora os que são organizados pelo próprio SOPt.

Particularmente, eu não vejo nenhum problema e inclusive me interesso em poder fazer divulgação de outros eventos aqui.

Gostaria de entender quais são os requisitos para que postagens com essas sejam autorizadas (e inclusive divulgadas com a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque)).

Pontos que observei:

1. São eventos relacionados à programação :)
2. A postagem oferece algum tipo de promoção para os usuários do site

Tem mais algum requisito? Tem que entrar em contato com alguém antes?

Comment: Julgo que é privilégio dos moderadores.

Comment: Vi um evento no SO espanhol, que o SOes é inclusive um parceiro do evento e achei interessante. [https://www.pycon.co/](https://www.pycon.co/)
Juntar Universidades, StackOverflow, empresas, etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eu perguntei para outros moderadores/CMs no chat privado e aos usuários no chat público se achavam que era abusivo, consideraram que não, no contexto específico.

Pelo histórico, dentro dos critérios já observados, sendo algo que ajude integrar a comunidade e sem fins lucrativos (opiniões minhas, pode ser que aceitam outros), acredito não ter problemas com qualquer evento, mas seria bom avisar moderadores ou algum CM antes de postar para ver se está tudo ok.

Answer (score 12):

Só pra constar: o SO em inglês tem uma medalha de prata chamada *"not a robot"*, especificamente para pessoas que [participam presencialmente de certos eventos](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot).

Também tivemos perguntas no meta que [pediam participação em pesquisas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pesquisa).

Eu acho que se o anúncio não for apenas uma propaganda gratuita, e se o que for anunciado for positivo para a comunidade, vale a pena ter a publicação por aqui.